# animate a div to a specific value with slideToggle() (more/less function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$("div").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>

<div style="height:240px; width:320px; border:1px solid tan; background:beige; padding:10px">text</div>
<a href=javascript:;>more/less</a>
```

hi coder,
i want to toogle a div from 80px/320px to 240px/320px with animate.
is this possible with slideToggle() or do i need an own function?
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass()` and pass in a number for the speed of animation.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/qFNYK/).

Keep in mind this requires jQuery UI.